# ADB Shell command that can test MLS / SPC codes?

Tags: adb, shell

I am a Republic Wireless subscriber with the Motorola Defy XT. The Defy is a decent phone, but unfortunately very little space has been dedicated to internal application storage (300MB) and often we are running out of space so we are on a quest to get root access to alleviate our issues. Sadly, RW has not provided us with the MLS / SPC code to modify the device.

My question is, is there an Android shell command that I can issue that will directly / indirectly test the validity of an MLS / SPC code. In other words, a command that changes a setting that requires the MLS code to be passed along as a parameter.

My hope is that I can write a script that will test all possible combinations of the six digit integer.